# Is it possible for someone to run for Senator and (be) Representative at the same time?

Tags: united-states, election, congress

In the US, can someone run for Senate while

- running for a House of Representatives seat at the same time, or
- (run for Senate) while still holding a seat in the House of Representatives?

Since a state might have "safe" Representative seats in some districts, but contested Senate seats, can this kind of "upgrade with a backstop" strategy be employed by some politician(s) or is there some formal rule against it?

Comment: The general category is "resign-to-run" law. There are similar articles at [Ballotpedia](https://ballotpedia.org/Resign-to-run_law) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resign-to-run_laws), however these articles are out-of-date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The laws on running for more than one office at once vary from state to state.

For example, in Ohio, there is no prohibition from running for two federal offices at the same time, though it is prohibited to run for a state and federal office concurrently ([ORC 3513.052](http://codes.ohio.gov/orc/3513.052)).  On the other hand, in Oregon, it is prohibited to run for more than one office at the same election ([ORS 249.013](https://www.oregonlaws.org/ors/249.013)).

Comment: To make this good answer complete, to the OP’s second question the answer is probably yes in all the states, since the rep would be up for re-election anyway, so they could run for senate instead of running for re-election to the House.